# How to copy files from multiple Azure VM to Azure Storage automatically and access then

Tags: windows, azure, powershell, azure-devops, azure-storage-account

We have approx 15 servers each server has different log files. Developer need to access that log files. We want then to access that files without login to VM. We figured out AZURE STORAGE ACCOUNT. Our requirement is every vm logs has to sync with respective azure Blob or File share from azure devops. We found AZcopy. But draw back is we need approx 15 pipeline to run periodically for every 30min to get lastest logs. Also we figured out windows scheduler which is not accepted by client.
All servers are Windows.

Is there any other and best way to send all logs files to blob or file share (Automation) and access that files using CDN or storage explorer. Even if it is other method also fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save logs files of VM to Azure Blobs and don't want to use the pipelines for the process then you can use the **Azure Log Analytics** for your work.

The Azure Log Analytics agent can collects telemetry from Windows virtual machines in any cloud, on-premises machines, and sends it collected data to your **Log Analytics workspace in Azure Monitor**. Then you can send the custom logs of VM to the **Azure Blob Storage or even in the event hub**.

In each and every VM you need to check the diagnostic settings and enable logs against the log analytics. Once configured it will be sending logs directly to the Azure Storage, no automation is required.

[image]

[image]

I would suggest to read this [Azure Activity log](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/essentials/activity-log) and [Log Analytics agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/agents/log-analytics-agent) document for more information.